# HTML - keep inline-block elements from dropping down

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this layout....

[image: layout]

I have everything pretty much laid out but the different boxes are dropping down when I resize the browser window. I want them to stay where they are and scale.

I am trying to get it to work using display:inline-block.

```
<body>
<header>header</header>
<article>
    <div class="col_left">
        <div class="col_left_top margin_18bot">img</div>
        <div class="col_left_bot">box1</div>
        <div class="col_left_bot margin_18left_18bot">box2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_right margin_18left_18bot">box3</div>
</article>
```

```
 html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.margin_18left_18bot {
    margin: 0px 0px 18px 18px;
}
.margin_18bot {
    margin: 0px 0px 18px 0px;
}
body {
    max-width: 1080px;
    min-width: 850px;
    margin: auto;
}
header {
    background-color: brown;
    height: 153px;
}
article {
    padding: 18px;
}
.col_left {
    float: left;
    width: 66.3%;
    max-width: 690px;
}
.col_left_top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    max-width: 690px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.col_left_bot {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 48.697912%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-width: 336px;
}
.col_right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32.1854%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 1070px;
    max-width: 336px;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arsinek/h8L51f3f/)....   *fixed fiddle wasnt showing properly before

Comment: Instead of using `px`, have you looked at using `vw`, where each unit represents 1% of the window's width? https://jsfiddle.net/61hj9drn/

Comment: I think my fiddle was broken before. Im trying to scale divs not text.

Comment: This is a duplicate of countless questions, try searching.

Comment: Sure. `vw` should work for the width of divs, too.

Comment: I have researched and havent gotten it to work.

Comment: James I dont think thats going to work because they need to be a percentage of another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is because you are setting their `width` in percent yet you define those margins in `px` which will eventually won't have a total of `width` of `100%` when you scale down.

To fix this, you have to do the following:

**Change this :**

```
.col_left {
    float: left;
    width: 66.3%; 
    max-width: 690px;
}

.col_right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32.1854%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 1070px;
    max-width: 336px;
}
```

**To:**

```
.col_left {
    float: left;
    width: calc(67% - 9px); 
    max-width: 690px;
}

.col_right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(33% - 9px);
    background-color: red;
    height: 1070px;
    max-width: 336px;
}
```

The reason I use :

```
calc(33% - 9px); and width: calc(67% - 9px);
```

is because the `margin-left` is `18px` so we have to divide it by two.

Also when doing an `inline-block` take note that if you format your structure like below, you will have a space between them because of the newline:

```
<div class="col_left_bot">box1</div>
<div class="col_left_bot margin_18left_18bot">box2</div>
```

To fix that, get rid of the newline. It will get ugly, but it will do the trick

```
<div class="col_left_bot">box1</div><div class="col_left_bot margin_18left_18bot">box2</div>
```

**Update** to give further explanation regarding the issue on `percentage` with a margin set as `px`

Let's say you have `100px` container and `49%` width on 2 elements with `2px` margin.

Let's compute :

```
100 * .49 x 2 + 2 = 100 // correct for this scale
```

But what if the container scales down to 50px?

Computation :

```
50 * .49 x 2 + 2 = 51 // it doesn't total to 50px
```

Which is why your other elements go down when the container scales down.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robincarlo84/j17xtxen/)

Comment: That does seem to work. So my divs were getting pushed down because they exceded the size of their container? I dont understand because shouldnt they have just scaled down being that they were using percentages?

Comment: That makes sense. So how do people usually handle column sizing and margins in grid systems? Thats sort of what Im going for on a very simplistic scale. Do they use this calc technique or something else?

Comment: @Arsinek On grid systems I know, they use `float` and use `padding` for the spacing instead of `margin` to their columns. The margin takes places on their row container. Regarding to their width, they don't use `calc` but use only `percentages` since they won't have `margins` with them. 12 columns = 8.333% each, 2 columns = 50% each. This [link](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) might help.